# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Tags: json, flutter, dart, backend

**this is my user_model.dart :**

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final userModel = userModelFromJson(jsonString);
import 'dart:convert';

UserModel userModelFromJson(String str) => UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userModelToJson(UserModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserModel {
  Data data;

  UserModel({
    required this.data,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": data.toJson(),
      };
}

class Data {
  bool? isAdmin;
  String fullName;
  String email;
  String profileImageUrl;
  String? gender;
  String? phoneNumber;
  GeoLocation? geoLocation;
  String? address;
  String? aadharCardUrl;
  String? upiId;
  bool? isEligible;

  Data({
    this.isAdmin,
    required this.fullName,
    required this.email,
    required this.profileImageUrl,
    this.gender,
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.geoLocation,
    this.address,
    this.aadharCardUrl,
    this.upiId,
    this.isEligible,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        isAdmin: json["isAdmin"] ?? false, // Default to false
        fullName: json["full_name"] ?? "NA", // Default to "NA"
        email: json["email"] ?? "NA", // Default to "NA"
        profileImageUrl: json["profileImageUrl"] ?? "NA", // Default to "NA"
        gender: json["gender"] ?? "NA", // Default to "NA"
        phoneNumber: json["phoneNumber"] ?? "NA", // Default to "NA"
        geoLocation: json["geoLocation"] != null
            ? GeoLocation.fromJson(json["geoLocation"])
            : null,
        address: json["address"] ?? "NA",
        aadharCardUrl: json["aadharCardUrl"] ?? "NA",
        upiId: json["upiId"] ?? "NA",
        isEligible: json["isEligible"] ?? false, // Default to false
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "isAdmin": isAdmin,
        "full_name": fullName,
        "email": email,
        "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl,
        "gender": gender,
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
        "geoLocation": geoLocation?.toJson(), // Convert to JSON if not null
        "address": address,
        "aadharCardUrl": aadharCardUrl,
        "upiId": upiId,
        "isEligible": isEligible,
      };
}

class GeoLocation {
  String latitude;
  String longitude;

  GeoLocation({
    required this.latitude,
    required this.longitude,
  });

  factory GeoLocation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GeoLocation(
        latitude: json["latitude"] ?? "NA", // Set default value "NA"
        longitude: json["longitude"] ?? "NA", // Set default value "NA"
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude,
      };
}
```

**and this is auth_api_service.dart :**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import '../../../global_index.dart';

class AuthApiService {
  final customHttpService = CustomHttpService(baseUrl: ApiConstants.baseUrl);

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createNewUser() async {
    final user = await GoogleSignInApi.login();

    if (user != null) {
      final pathSegments = [ApiConstants.user, ApiConstants.create];

      final requestBody = {
        'full_name': user.displayName,
        'email': user.email,
        'profileImageUrl': user.photoUrl
      };

      final response = await customHttpService.makeSuperExtendedRequest(
        'POST',
        '',
        pathSegments,
        data: requestBody,
      );

      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(response);
      }

      // Parse and return token and user data
      if (response['token'] is String && response['token'] != '') {
        final userModel = UserModel.fromJson(response['data']);
        return {'token': response['token'], 'user': userModel};
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to create user');
      }
      // return requestBody;
    } else {
      SnackbarUtils.showSnackbar(
        type: SnackbarType.error,
        message: 'Sign in Failed',
      );
      throw Exception('Google sign in failed');
    }
  }
}
```

**this the  print(response) :**

```
{message: User logged in successfully, data: {_id: 64db9d390fd7a3d6ffa8c6b0, isAdmin: false, full_name: Ramith K S, email: ramithgowdakundoor123@gmail.com, profileImageUrl: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AAcHTterxJeBp7WYHN0b6FeQIlc1ZT7-GFjmHHb28Z2ZUJ0U3PAI, gender: Other, geoLocation: null, isEligible: false, __v: 0}, token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NGRiOWQzOTBmZDdhM2Q2ZmZhOGM2YjAiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTIxODk3NTEsImV4cCI6MTY5MjE5MzM1MX0.4Mcu9LaohhB8LAz3QJlm3uWGQYO2h2I96YVKXE2Po2s}
```

**but its throwing a following error :**

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

and its pointing out here :
  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
      );
```

The error Im encountering, "Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')", indicates that the problem lies in the UserModel.fromJson factory method. This error is occurring because the data field in the JSON response seems to be null, which means that the JSON structure you're trying to parse doesn't match the expected structure.

The UserModel.fromJson factory method expects a JSON map with a "data" field containing the user data, and it tries to parse this data using the Data.fromJson method. However, in the response you provided, the "data" field is not null but it doesn't seem to contain a valid JSON object. To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the JSON structure you're trying to parse matches the structure defined in your UserModel and Data classes. Double-check the response from the server to make sure it's providing the expected JSON structure with all the necessary fields.

Additionally, I want to consider handling cases where the "data" field is missing or null in a more graceful way to prevent these kind of exceptions. You can add a conditional check before parsing the "data" field to ensure it's not null before attempting to parse it. This can help you handle unexpected or incomplete responses more effectively and prevent crashes in my app.

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: You already included the answer in your question...

Comment: bro, if you know the answer please provide the code .